# Multiple Calculations in CASE Statement SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the following SQL Code to work however I am struggling with finding out how to do multiple calculations with a CASE Statement, here is the Code:

```
SELECT 
dbo.Table1.PrimaryKeyID,
  CASE

       WHEN (number1 >0 AND number2 = 0) 
             THEN number1 = number1 + CalcView.Quantity

       WHEN (number1 =0 AND number2 <=0) 
             THEN number3 = number3 + CalcView.Quantity,
                  number2 = number2 - CalcView.Quantity

       WHEN (number1 =0 AND number2 >0) 
             THEN number3 = number3 + number2 
                  number1 = number1 + (CalcView.Quantity - number2)
                  number2 = 0
END
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN CalcViewON Table1.PrimaryKeyID= CalcView.PrimaryKeyID
WHERE Table1.PrimaryKeyID= CalcView.PrimaryKeyID
```

- The view is present to get rid of a **SUM()** which would force me to use **GROUP** **BY**
- The names are not what I am using, I have changed them to make it easier to understand..

As you can see I have just put the calculations within the **THEN** at the moment, please could anyone point me in the right direction of how to get this statement to work? thankyou for any help you can give me

Examples:

```
Case 1
Number1 = 5
Number2 = 0
CalcView.Quantity = 3

5 = 5 + 3 (8)


Case 2
Number 1 = 5
Number 2 = 3
Number 3 = 2
CalcView.Quantity = 3

2 = 2 + 3 (5)
3 = 3 - 3 (0)


Case 3
Number 1 = 5
Number 2 = 3
Number 3 = 2
CalcView.Quantity = 6

2 = 2 + 3 (5)
1 = 1 + (6 – 3) (4)
Number2 = 0
```

the aim: to update number1, number2 and number3 based on the 3 WHEN statements. currently I am using a select statement to make sure I am achieving the correct outputs...

What alternatives are there to CASE statements that could help me achieve my goal? Thanks Again

Comment: Your syntax is all wrong, are you trying to select 4 columns in your example? If so then you need three separate case statements. Can you provide an example output of what you want your query to return

Comment: In addition to Tobseys questions, could you provide sample input? You can use http://sqlfiddle.com/ as a base to generate a sample scenario for us

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. Your first two "Whens" return the same value. Then in your third and fourth "When" you are setting variables? You can't set variables inside a case statement, you can only return a value. So "number1 = case when (number1 = 0 and number2 = 0) then 15 else 14 end" would be how you set a variable with a case statement.

Comment: I think your problem is you're trying to use a sql case statement like a C switch statement. SQL Case won't let you do that, it wants you to return a scalar based on conditions. You may be best populating variables with your data and then using If...else statements with code blocks in order to achieve what you're trying to do here

Comment: I do C# all the time which is my issue as you are correctly pointing out, I have written the exact code out in C# in minutes and I know it would work, im having quite a bit of difficulty in converting it to SQL to run within a procedure. What SQL functions exist that could help me achieve my goal if It is not possible to call multiple calculations within a CASE WHEN statement?

Comment: Should you first `WHEN` read `number1 =  number1 + CalcView.Quantity` ie, are you trying to calculate `number1`, `number2` & `number3`?

Comment: yes it should read number1 = number1 + CalcView.Quantity

Comment: a **CASE** statement will always return 1 value, nothing more  nothing less

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to calculate `number1`, `number2` and `number3` using a single `CASE...WHEN...END` statement, this will not work - you need 3 distinct case statements.

If I understand your logic, this should do it

```
SELECT 
dbo.Table1.PrimaryKeyID,
  CASE
    WHEN (number1 >0 AND number2 = 0) 
       THEN number1 + CalcView.Quantity
    WHEN  (number1 =0 AND number2 >0) 
       THEN number1 + (CalcView.Quantity - number2)
    ELSE
       number1
  END AS number1,
  CASE 
    WHEN(number1 =0 AND number2 <=0) 
       THEN number2 - CalcView.Quantity
    WHEN  (number1 =0 AND number2 >0) 
       THEN 0
    ELSE
       number2
  END AS number2,
  CASE
    WHEN (number1 =0 AND number2 <=0) 
       THEN number3 + CalcView.Quantity
    WHEN  (number1 =0 AND number2 >0) 
       THEN number3 + number2 
    ELSE
       number3
  END AS number3
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN CalcViewON Table1.PrimaryKeyID= CalcView.PrimaryKeyID
WHERE Table1.PrimaryKeyID= CalcView.PrimaryKeyID
```